# Please help with this GRE Quant. Comparison question (Triangle Geometry)

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Picture of Question]

My thought process was that since side AD = DC, and *m* and *n* are their opposite respective angles, then
*m* and *n* must be equal to each other. My GRE practice book says that this is wrong and that the answer is D (The relationship cannot be determined from the information given). Maybe it has something to do with angle BCD = 60 degrees, but I thought that this was irrelevant because of the previous information. Can anyone explain? I have never been good with geometry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagine if BCD was an equilateral triangle (60/60/60). Angle ADB would be 120 degrees, so angle $m$ could not be 60 degrees.

Comment: Move the point B along BC and you will find that m and n are changed. In other way - for every angel A between 0 to 180, you could find a triangle which meets the requirements.